# What is the foramt of objects in openstack api respose?

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

Hi i have openstack installed and i want to interact with its services via APIs and use the response in my functions for example when i send a request to nova API to get the list of servers existing it  returned a resonse like this :
([http://controller:8774/v2/57fcadbcb37349bfa3a4757f03b49287/servers/3312c5ac-28c1-4222-9ca9-32e16e69fc78', u'rel': u'self'}, {u'href': u'http://controller:8774/57fcadbcb37349bfa3a4757f03b49287/servers/3312c5ac-28c1-4222-9ca9-32e16e69fc78', u'rel': u'bookmark'}]....
I didn't understand yhis format so can you pleae tell me what is this format of data and how i will use it Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the format is JSON.  you can read more about JSON here:

http://www.json.org/

the mechanism is RESTful. you can read more about that here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Answer (score 0):

- all api documents: http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref.html
- nova api document: http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-compute-v2.1.html
- for your specific case: http://developer.openstack.org/api-ref-compute-v2.1.html#listServers